# How to create and output box and how to use it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, dd

I am working on a simple Dice Roller for my D&D games and the code is working and everything, I just do not know how to make an output box for when the button is pressed. I want to press the button and have the randint output in the output box next to the button.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Jou.png)

Comment: Don't post your code as an link to an image. Put the code as formatted text into the question itself.

Comment: You can edit your question by pressing the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65082800/edit) button under your question.

Comment: Most tkinter tutorials can answer this question for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty label right before/after your button.

```
result_label = Label(root, text = "")
result_label.grid(row = 0, column =1)
```

Then, you can update the text by adding the following inside your function :

```
result_label.config(text = randint(1,6))
```

This will replace the empty text of the label by a random number.
If you want to keep the print output you'll have to save the value of randint(1,6) in a variable and use it as an input for both the text label and the print function.

Comment: I appreciate your helping but your variable naming style is making me twitch. Python names should be lower_snake_case. Please read PEP8.

Comment: Variable naminge style corrected. Was not aware of PEP8. Thanks for the tip.